# Not able get rid of error for launching chrome with selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver" , 
     "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Seleniumdriver\\chromedriver.exe");

static  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Always shows an error at the `,` and set property. Also, eclipse not defining the reason for the error

imported the header file as well. Do I need to import any jars in build path for launching chrome?

Comment: You probably did something wrong. Are those 2 lines in one method?

Comment: You are probably adding the code in class definition (not within a method). You can use a static code block to set the system property.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/Drivers/chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Create a folder as drivers in your current project and keep the chromeDriver.exe in that and use the above code,Hopefully your problem will be sloved.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case, it should look like at least something like this.

```
 public class Foo {

    @Test
    public void openWebPage(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://google.com");
    }
}
```

You should also try placing your chromedriver on the root of your C:/ drive just for good measure.